# Open a file from a dynamic path in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that opens a excel file formats and closes. When I use only the network path, the code works perfectly. When I add the dynamic part of the path which is  "//mynetworkpath/year-month/complete", the code doesn't find the file. So the path is like this:   "//mynetworkpath/2019-12/complete". Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub format_excel()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim mypath As String

Dim file As String

mypath = "//mynetworkpath/" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm") & "/" & "complete"

file = Dir(mypath & "myfilename_*.xlsx")

If Not IsEmpty(file) Then

   Workbooks.Open (mypath & file)
```

Comment: It worked until I added the date part....

Comment: In VBA the path is built using backslash... So, I would suggest to use "\" instead of "/".

Comment: You might want to check whether `mypath` contains the text you're expecting... And you probably need to add a folder separator (`/` or `\` after `complete`. Or between `mypath` and `myfilename` in the `Dir`.

Comment: Suggest you use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of an explicit string when building your path. I'd also suggest checking that the folder exists and that the file exists before trying to open the file.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your reply. The Path does exist and the files are there. I added "/" after complete as Cindy suggested and it worked :). Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: FYI you can check for a slash, and add automatically in a single line: `myPath = iif(Right$(myPath, 1) <>"\", myPath & "\", myPath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danielle,
If it was working before you added the date thing, I think its just because you are missing a forward slash:
Replace:

```
mypath = "//mynetworkpath/" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm") & "/" & "complete"
```

with

```
mypath = "//mynetworkpath/" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm") & "/" & "complete" & "/"
```

and just do

```
Workbooks.Open (file)
```